# WordPress with SOFT 404 in Google Search Console (WMT) What causes Q82019309.com?

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, 404, soft-404

My [brothers site](https://www.blackforce.co.uk) that I designed for him awhile has hundreds of SOFT 404's reported in  Google's Search Console formerly Webmaster Tools. Generally I find fixing soft 404 easy but this has me a little stumped. All the soft errors are returning a odd string that contains `Q82019309.com` with the occasional sub folder `Aristocrat`within the string `/?=`.

*The 404's generally look something like:*

- Encoded: `/search/%E5%A4%A7%E5%A5%96%E6%80%BB%E4%BB%A3Q82019309.com`
- Decoded: `/search/大奖总代Q82019309.com`

The linked from information provides:

- Encoded: `/?s=%E5%A4%A7%E5%A5%96%E6%80%BB%E4%BB%A3Q82019309.com`
- Decoded: `/?s=大奖总代Q82019309.com`

At first I believed this was an isolated issue but upon investigating I discovered that this issue actually affects thousands of websites and someone must know the cause. When I Google [Q82019309.com WordPress](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Q82019309.com%20WordPress) or [Aristocrat Q82019309.com](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sclient=psy-ab&safe=off&client=firefox-b&biw=2560&bih=1300&q=Aristocrat%20Q82019309.com&oq=Aristocrat%20Q82019309.com&gs_l=serp.3...65523.65860.5.66066.2.2.0.0.0.0.61.118.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.uKOfUxQ_F_A&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&bvm=bv.144224172,d.ZGg&ech=1&psi=UlaCWIm_LqffgAaX3ZG4BQ.1484936787893.61&ei=O1mCWKK5O6HAgAb6voyoBQ&emsg=NCSR&noj=1) I'm overwhelmed with the amount of results, including some of highly reputable sites such as:

- [Screaming Frog](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.screamingfrog.co.uk%2F%3Fpost_type%255B%255D%3Dfaqs%26s%3D%25E5%25A4%25A7%25E5%25A5%2596PT%25E8%2580%2581%25E8%2599%258E%25E6%259C%25BA%25E9%25A6%2596%25E5%25AD%2598%25E6%25B4%25BB%25E5%258A%25A8%2BQ82019309.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=UlaCWOacLYbW8AfKvK94)
- [Ellenshop](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ellenshop.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Daristocrat%25E7%2594%25A8%25E9%2592%2588%25E4%25B8%258A%25E5%2588%2586%25E6%258A%2580%25E6%259C%25AFq82019309.com%26type%3Dproduct&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=l1eCWJjnD4bW8AfKvK94)
- [Saver Stores UK](http://www.savers.co.uk/search/Aristocrat%E6%94%BE%E4%B8%80%E5%8F%B0%E7%8A%AF%E6%B3%95%E5%90%97Q82019309.com/feed/rss2/)

Question(s):

So what is causing these soft 404 errors with string `Q82019309.com` with or without `Aristocrat`.

Comment: Your site has been hacked. Q82019309.com is compromised.

Comment: Going to the site Q82019309.com says its an attack site and I agree that its dodgy but I find it hard to believe that all these sites have been hacked with something that uses a query string in the search. There is literary hundreds of thousands of websites that are reporting Q82019309.com... highly reputable ones... surely these are not all hacked?

Comment: The links appear to be all spammy. A very typical profile. As well, this seems to be specific to WP sites. This seems to be fairly recent, within just a few days (4 or so). Check the WP install to make sure everything is up to date. See: https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?query=wordpress&search_type=all&cves=on

Comment: Was discovered over a week ago 13th.

Comment: Think I'll have to look through the errors.log and access.logs to identify if someone has attempted or got in via a new hack.

Comment: There are a lot of new vulnerabilities just this month. See the link above for the details. Cheers!!

Comment: I've seen spammers use this to get mentions of their site into other people's logs and URLs. You can use a rel=canonical on the pages, or even set up a htaccess directive to redirect away from the URL patterns, but in the end it's no big deal (soft-404's are fine for this kind of thing).

Comment: I've added the: Disallow: /search
Disallow: /?s= to Robots.txt but the Soft 404's keep coming back although in much smaller numbers. They are all the same spammy pages with Q82019309.com in and they are definitely returning a proper 404 page so why do they keep coming back in the Console when they've been marked as fixed?

Answer (score 2):

We were having the same issue at [wisepops.com](https://wisepops.com) since the 3rd January 2017.

Google is complaining about Soft 404 even if indexing is disabled on these pages. 
The Wordpress search page has by default this meta:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">
```

I decided to make search pages without results return a 404 HTTP code. Since the search query is in the URL, it is fine to handle it this way.

For Wordpress, I added at the end of my theme's functions.php:

```
/*---------------------------------------------------*/
/*  SEARCH PAGES WITHOUT RESULTS SEND 404 HTTP CODE  */
/*---------------------------------------------------*/
function wisepops_search_404_code() {
    if (is_search() && !have_posts()) {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
        $GLOBALS['wp_query']->is_404 = true;
    }
}
add_action('get_header', 'wisepops_search_404_code');
```

Comment: @wisepops.com: I have the same problem with this stupid Search-Spam Attack. Thank you for the code! It worked great for me! Now empty search returns a clean 404 and that's cool. Sincerly, Mitschu

Comment: Would this send an actual user that makes a search and gets zero results to a 404 page as well?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your something is linking to your site search functionality with bad queries.  Those search queries get "no results found".  Googlebot is finding those links and you are allowing Googlebot to crawl your site search.   Because of the "no results", Google is detecting them as "soft 404".

Letting Google crawl your site search results is a big no-no.   It can get your entire site penalized by Google.   See [Matt Cutts: Search results in search results](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/search-results-in-search-results/).   You should disallow all crawling of search results using *robots.txt*:

```
Disallow: /search
Disallow: /?s=
```

Then Googlebot will not crawl those URLs and report errors there either.

Comment: Stephen, did this reslove the soft 404s? I've actually added this to my robots.txt and marked all of my soft 404's on the search page as fixed. Once I verify, I'll mark this as correct. But this seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin sorted the problem for me:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-search-slug/