# Google Search Console reports increase in Soft 404's

Tags: google-search-console, soft-404

I received an alert this morning from Google Search Console reporting that there has been a sharp increase in "Soft 404's". Here is an example of the url that is triggering the 404:

```
search/%E5%A4%A7%E5%A5%96%E5%A8%B1%E4%B9%90%E6%80%8E%E4%B9%88%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD%E4%B8%8D%E4%BA%86+Q82019309.com.com/
```

Which is reportedly linked from here:

```
https://www.example.com/?s=%E5%A4%A7%E5%A5%96%E5%A8%B1%E4%B9%90%E6%80%8E%E4%B9%88%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD%E4%B8%8D%E4%BA%86+Q82019309.com.com
```

I'm confused by what could be triggering this? It seems like a bot would be doing something like this but why would Google be reporting this as a Soft 404 when it really doesn't exist anyway?

Comment: We have gotten this question a few times already. This is a result of a compromised system creating links to what it thinks is another compromised system. If you are getting 404 errors, your system may not be compromised. **Be safe anyway.** Check your CMS, templates, plug-ins, Java code, tools, etc. for vulnerabilities here: https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search?execution=e2s1 Update all code that you can or at least find vulnerable. Make sure that your site is clean by checking databases, files, etc. Cheers!!

Comment: The "Linked From" page is returning a 200 status code which is correct because it's the search result page with the ?s= query. So maybe do some searches in my database to make sure links have not been created?

Comment: Yes. Definitely. This is part of a larger spam hack pattern where links are made from one compromised system to another. If on your side these links to your site are returning 404s, you do not have to worry about the links per se'. Just make sure your site is not compromised. These links in particular have only just showed up a few months ago so it is a relatively new hack.

Comment: I actually found this similiar question posted. After reading through it, seems like adding /search and /?s= to the robots.txt file might be a good solution? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103043/wordpress-with-soft-404-in-google-search-console-wmt-what-causes-q82019309-com

Comment: That may help! That is a newer answer from the day that Q was posted. I up-voted it since it seems to be the simplest way to help reduce the 404 notices. Try it and let us know! Cheers!!

Comment: Seems like google bot would have an algorithm to filter out this kind of garbage by now